# How to calculate day of the week provided the day and month

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is strictly set in the year of 2014. However, I want to know if I am heading in the right direction. This is what I have so far:

```
def day(d,m): # Function for determining day name for a given date.
    """Where m is an integer from 1 through 12 expressing a month, and d is an integer from 
    1 through 31 expressing the day-part of a date in 2014."""

    day = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa']
    weekday = (d + (2.6*m - 0.2) -2*20 + 2014 + (2014//4) + (20//4))
    return day[weekday]
```

Comment: `DateTime` instantly fixes this for you. Just check the docs. If you give in the date to the construct; you can use the formatter to output the `day`. Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `datetime`, this should work:

```
def day(d, m):
    day = (sum((31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)[:m-1]) + d + 3) % 7
#           ^                                                     ^      ^   ^  ^ ^
#           '---- adding up the days in the months                |      |   |  | |
#                   up to but not including the current month ----'      |   |  | |
#                                  plus the current day of the month ----'   |  | |
#                                  and the day of the week on 12/31/2013 ----'  | |
#                    modulus (%) is what's left over after integer division ----' |
#                                                        seven days in a week ----'
```

Answer (score 7):

[Don't reinvent the wheel](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 16).strftime('%a')
'Sun'
```

---

[Or as a number](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 16).weekday()
6
```

Which you can then pass into your `day` list

Comment: Ahh I have considered using import datetime, however, I have not covered that section yet. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Cleaner to do `from datetime import datetime`. Or even even give it a new (shorter) name :)

Comment: @Yozuru, if you only need it for 2014, then make a list of how many days are in each month, add up all the previous months, plus the current day, plus the day of the week on 1/1/2014. Modulus (%) 7 and you're done.

Comment: @mhlester, so this would use Zeller's congruence if i'm correct. and the list would look like 1<=m<=12 and 1<=d<=31.

Comment: i am not familiar with Zeller's congruence. just doing the math